# How to get Job attributes in ActiveJob callback methods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback, rails-activejob

Rails 4.2, active_jobs, callback_methods

In the perform method of a custom Job I created a new record (and upload a file to S3).  How can I pass, or get, that new records id in the after_perform callback?  I want to send an email after_perform with a link to the S3 document...but, not sure how to get the id inside the after_perform method.  According to the docs you can use job.attributes, but I get 'undefined method attributes'.

I could move the mailer call into the perform method, but Id rather handle it correctly using callbacks.  I am unsure how to access attributes (or where those attributes originate) outside of the perform method.

I tried to do some detective work (to determine what attributes were available to the callback) by placing this in the callback:

```
 puts "job: #{ job }"
```

or

```
puts "job: #{ job.attributes }"
```

or

```
puts "job: #{ job.attributes.first }"
```

none of these worked, and all resulted in undefined 'attributes'.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to use `arguments` instead of `attributes`:

```
after_perform do |job|
    record = job.arguments.first
    # Do something with the record
end
```

Where my perform method looks like:

```
def perform(record)
    # Perform stuff
end
```

Comment: I'm getting arguments empty don't know why.. How to pass job arguments in callback